# Cannot customise Navbar created with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

My bootstrap navbar cannot be customised in CSS. I have inserted my CSS code as an example. It also doesn't work when I drop the id `#nav` and use `.navbar-inverse;` instead... The CSS colours used are just to see if a change is being made.

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CscWI.jpg) of what appears...

Many thanks for any help/suggestions! :)

```css
@media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
    .container{
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}

/* ----- BACKGROUND ----- */
body {
    background-image: url('../img/harley.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: -10px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}


/* ----- BODY ----- */

#header {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


#header h1 {

  font-family: "Trocchi", serif;
  color: #3E2F1B;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#header h2 {

  font-family: "Trocchi", serif;
  color: #644A26;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* -- RESPONSIVE HEADER (need to add more) */

@media all and (max-width: 2000px) {
  #header h1 {
    font-size: 5.7em;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1500px) {
  #header h1 {
    font-size: 5.0em;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #header h1 {
    font-size: 4.3em;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 750px) {
  #header h1 {
    font-size: 3.7em;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
  #header h1 {
    font-size: 3.0em;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  #header h1 {
    font-size: 2.3em;
  }
}
<<<<<<< HEAD

/* ----- NAVIGATION BAR ----- */

#nav {
  background-color: pink;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>Home / Harley's Haunts</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- import font "Trocchi" -->
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Trocchi');
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>


<!-- ***** HEADER ***** -->

<div class="container-fluid" id="header">
  <h1>HARLEY'S HAUNTS</h1>
  <h2>Where dogs are welcome in Aberdeen!</h2>
</div>

<!-- ***** NAVIGATION BAR ***** -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Pet-Friendly Venues<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Shops</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cafes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pubs/Bars</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Restuarants</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you're using color names, there's no `#` in front. `#` only goes for hex values like `#FFFFFF`. Pink is pink, no `#` in front.

Comment: Whoops! Silly error - I'm tired from trying to resolve this problem. When I remove the #, it still doesn't change anything...

Comment: Inspect element and check if something is overriding your colors, then you could try applying it to a lower level of hierarchy, or if you really wanna force it use the `!important` , in your case `background-color: pink !important;`

Comment: No such luck, I'm afraid :( At any level of the hierarchy

Comment: `<<<<<<< HEAD` Is this part a mistake or it's included in a file?

Comment: It inserted itself automatically. No idea how it appeared. I'm working with a partner on this and she doesn't know how it got there either. I think it appeared after I wrote the @media CSS lines

Comment: I deleted the <<<<<<< HEAD and it works now. Wow, what a relief! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me resolve this!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: @stefan leave that as an answer so he can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<<<<<<< HEAD` from the file as it's not a valid CSS syntax.